# proper way to handle max line length python

Tags: python

**Que-1** Break flake8 and black cycle

```
class TaskInfo(StrEnum):
   
   ABCDEFG_HELLOO_TASK_WELCOMEE_VALUE: str = "abcdefg_helloo_task_welcomee_value"
```

A message from Flake8 gives line too long (82 > 79 characters)

so I edit as below

```
class TaskInfo(StrEnum):
   
   ABCDEFG_HELLOO_TASK_WELCOMEE_VALUE: str = ("abcdefg_helloo_task" +
                                              "_welcomee_value")
```

Now I get message as Black would make changes. On running black, it reformat the string to original state.

**Que-2** Designing web pages

As above issue is with script code, I am also designing the web dashboard using dash plotly,
Here there are Rows and Columns inside each other(bootstrap way) which holds the different components like button etc
this makes line goes upto 150 characters.

what is right way to handle both Que-1 and Que-2?

Comment: You should make two separate question instead of combining them both in one question. Especially since they seem that they're not very related

Comment: PEP-8 asserts a maximum line length of 79, but then reverses itself a few paragraphs later to allow you to use whatever maximum line length your team agrees is acceptable. It's really only prescriptive regarding the line length of code intended to be added to the Python standard library. Black is a more prescriptive tool, but even it lets you choose the "correct" line length to enforce.

Comment: Note you don't need to use a `+` sign in your `str` definition as Python automatically concatenates string literals next to each other. It doesn't hurt anything though (that `+` operation is performed at compile time)

Comment: Hi kindall, Thanks. I was not aware of this.

Comment: Hi  12944qwerty, Thanks. I will create a new thread for Que-2. since for both questions I was getting flake8 issue, so I thought to merge both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both tools are configurable. `flake8` has a `--max-line-length` option to indicate which lines should be flagged as too long, and `black` has a `--line-length` option to indicate what length should be enforced.

PEP-8 itself is a little contradictory: the first line of its "Maximum Line Length" section baldly asserts

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.

but then acknowledges a few paragraphs later

> Some teams strongly prefer a longer line length. For code maintained exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this issue, it is okay to increase the nominal line length from 80 to 100 characters (effectively increasing the maximum length to 99 characters), provided that comments and docstrings are still wrapped at 72 characters.

So unless you are contributing code to the Python Standard Library, the correct answer is to choose what line length you (and your team) think is appropriate for your code, then configure *both* tools to abide by that line length.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VS Code. I added the both as suggested by @chepner and issue is resolved.

python > formatting: Black Args

```
--line-length=120
```

python > linting: Flake8 Args

```
--max-line-length=120
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add `# noqa` in front of the line greater than 79 characters to make flake8 ignore the error.

**Example:**

```
class TaskInfo(StrEnum):
   
   ABCDEFG_HELLOO_TASK_WELCOMEE_VALUE: str = "abcdefg_helloo_task_welcomee_value" # noqa
```

Comment: Hi mrrobot, Thanks. I did tired, but adding this on every other line is bit difficult task.